# Display 0 values as 0 instead of \0 in CSV files in Cognos reports

Tags: cognos, cognos-8

I am trying to run a CSV report in Cognos and it is displaying 0 values as \0. Could someone let me know if there is any way of displaying it as a 0. I tried to change the properties in Data Format but nothing works

Comment: Do mean you're running the report to CSV, or from a CSV file as the source?

Comment: Hi ANdrew, I am running the report to CSV

Comment: Maybe check your source?  Are you sure that the field is numeric?

Comment: I ran a test report on my Cognos 10.1.1 environment here and the 0 values all rendered as 0 in the CSV.  Are you sure there are 0 values in the report?  \0 is in some places shorthand for null, so it's possible that it's outputting a "null" in the field as \0 instead of a 0.

Answer (score 0):

\0 normally indicates a divide-by-zero result. You can override this default by setting the 'Divide by Zero Characters' property in Data Format to specify what to display on the report instead when this condition occurs.

Other properties to try if that one doesn't work:

- Missing Value Characters
- List item
- Zero Value Characters
- Numeric Overflow Characters
- "Not Applicable" Characters
- Any Error Characters